# In android, why UI can not be updated out of UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I know we should refresh UI in the main thread,and if we want to update UI in another thread we can use handler , blablabla...

but Why?  Maybe it has some thing to do with resource competition?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not only in android. In basically every gui framework the ui can be updated only from the ui thread. For more info [Why must UI elements always be created/updated from the UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148225/why-must-ui-elements-always-be-created-updated-from-the-ui-thread)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,and the link you give is really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Efficiency and responsiveness. Otherwise, you'd get inconsistent data and crashes, alternatively, the whole UI would have to lock and unlock resources constantly. You really wouldn't like the speed of such a user interface on a resource constrained mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So if you update the UI not on the UI thread you can experience weird problems that can be hard to track down and fix.