# Do I need EDT for each call to JLabel.setText()?

Tags: java, swing

Should all calls to JLabel.setText() go via EDT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all calls that change UI components must be done from the EDT.

For some background information you can check: [Why must UI elements always be created/updated from the UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148225/why-must-ui-elements-always-be-created-updated-from-the-ui-thread)

Comment: How about JLabel.getText()? It doesn't change UI of JLabel but it happens on JLabel

Comment: @Final Illusion: You need to call getText() on the EDT as well.